# Apply value to a dataframe after filtering another dataframe based on conditions

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

My question:
There are two dataframes and the info one is in progress to build.
What I want to do is filtering in reference dataframe based on the condition. When key is b, then apply value is 2 to the into table as whole column.
The output dataframe is the final one I want to do.

Dataframe (info)

```
+-----+-----+
|  key|value|
+-----+-----+
|    a|   10|
|    b|   20|
|    c|   50|
|    d|   40|
+-----+-----+
```

Dataframe (Reference)

```
+-----+-----+
|  key|value|
+-----+-----+
|    a|   42|
|    b|    2|
|    c|    9|
|    d|  100|
+-----+-----+
```

Below is the output I want:
Dataframe (Output)

```
+-----+-----+-----+
|  key|value|const|
+-----+-----+-----+
|    a|   10|    2|
|    b|   20|    2|
|    c|   50|    2|
|    d|   40|    2|
+-----+-----+-----+
```

I have tried several methods and below one is the latest one I tried, but system warm me that pyspark do not have loc function.

```
df_cal = (
    info
    .join(reference)
    .withColumn('const', reference.loc[reference['key']=='b', 'value'].iloc[0])
    .select('key', 'result', 'const')
)

df_cal.show()
```

And below is the warming that reminded by system:

```
AttributeError: 'Dataframe' object has no attribute 'loc'
```

Comment: So you want to add column `const` containing the value of `b` in the reference df if the reference df contains `b`?

Comment: I already know the reference df contains b so I need to filter the df and get the value of b, and add column const with the value of b into the info df, which looks like output df.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solve:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
```

---

```
target = 'b'
const = [i['value'] for i in df2.collect() if i['key'] == f'{target}']
df_cal = df1.withColumn('const', lit(const[0]))
df_cal.show()
```

---

```
+---+-----+-----+
|key|value|const|
+---+-----+-----+
|  a|   10|    2|
|  b|   20|    2|
|  c|   30|    2|
|  d|   40|    2|
+---+-----+-----+
```